# How do templates work in Meteor?

Tags: meteor

I try Meteor and have object in Mongo like this:

```
{ _id: iureuyhfiwuyerbe, "title": "title", "channel": "http://...", "desc": "description", "items" : [{ "title" : "This is title", "description" : "This is description", "link" : "http://123435", "pubDate" : "16 Oct 2014 20:46:00 +0400" }, { }, { } ... ] }
```

This news from RSS sources. I have many same documents in Db with it's own id.
I planned use `<select>` to switch RSS channel and display news items for selected channel. I need to bind this two values. How? I don't understand how I can display on client side items array values for each object in this array? Title, description etc.

This piece of my HTML

```
<template name="newsList">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        {{> channel}}
    </div>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        {{#each items}}
            {{> item}}
        {{/each}}
    </div>
</template>
```

I see channel, but not see Items.
How I can debug code in client side to view variables in template? I use Webstorm 9. Debugger is not stop on breakpoints in template.

Thank you.

Comment: Try going one level deeper in items. each items.title

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make template of item..

same strategy of showing channels to channel.

```
{{> items}}

{{item.title}}, {{item.description}} // and more..
```